# numbering from up to down

Tags: numbers

I want to translate a sentence from Persian to English, the sentence I want to say is "the children should tell numbers from up to down and conversely" but I am not sure does it correct?

Comment: No, the sentence doesn't make sense. Perhaps you might use a translation service first, and if you have a problem with a specific word or meaning, try looking for solutions on our other site [ell.se].

Comment: What is *numbering "from up to down"* intended to convey?

Comment: If you can give an example of what "the children telling numbers" actually means, that would help a lot; it's not obvious to us.  My guess is that it means a young child (age 4-6 or so) counting from 1 to 10 and then from 10 to 1.

Comment: You also asked this on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/182629/numbering-from-up-to-down). Please don't cross post.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that it might be difficult to obtain your intended meaning using a translation service. I hope that this answer might be of help.

In English, you would most commonly use a phrase like "**in descending and then ascending order**". This is the meaning of "**up to down and conversely**" in your question. You can say it the other way around if needed - *first in ascending (down to up) and then in descending (up to down) order*.

> **The numbered children will be arranged in ascending and**
>   **descending order**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ascending

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/descending

Comment: Yes, this works for mountains and tonnage estimates. But does it work for children? Children do not have `Up` or `Down` built-in values; how would you sort 15 children in descending order?

Comment: The children have been numbered - probably holding number cards in their hands. This is the reason the word "numbers" appears in the OP question - my interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

*The children should ***count*** from ***highest*** to ***lowest*** and conversely.*

"Count" can mean to name the numbers in order (going up):
*"Count to 5"* = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
*"What's the highest number you can count to?"*

To specify descending order you would say *"Count down from 5"* = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

"Count" can also mean to name the total number of things, for example *"I counted six chairs in the room."*